# Angular-animate - Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I have a strange issue. I want to include angular-animate in my AngularJS project - I am using AngularJS v1.2.6. I have added `angular-animate` to my bower file. It has downloaded and added to my HTML file in the source and it is pointing to the correct file (it loads in the browser). Now I need to add this as a dependancy, so I add the module to my app...

```
angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngResource',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngRoute',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'LocalStorageModule',
        'cookiesModule',
        'ngAnimate'
    ])
```

However as soon as Grunt kicks in detecting a file change and builds I get the following error:

```
Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- $compile
```

I've check the spelling, I've followed the instructions mentioned on https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate but I can't see why this isn't working or why I am getting the error! I've change the position of the dependency in the dependency array but this does nothing. Has anyone else experienced this? I'll continue researching this but if anyone has overcome or determined why this is happening please speak up! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Phew! I think I have fixed this... Bower seems to be the issue and solution!

I change from AngularJS 1.2.6 to 1.2.15 in my bower file and this resolved my issue:

so I changed this:

```
  "angular": "1.2.6"
```

to this

```
  "angular": "1.2.15"
```

Well, That only cost me 2 hours!

Comment: Setting "ngAnimate": "1.2.6" worked me for without need to downgrade angular

Comment: Took me an hour to find this one. I knew it was a version issue, but didn't get the right line up of versions till I read this post. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad this has solved the problem for others but it doesn't seem to explain why it happens, it is just a fix. I'm currently getting the same issue but this fix is no longer working :(

Comment: upgrading 1.2.0 beta RC3 to 1.3 fixed it for me.

Comment: if it's not working, just manually install the ngAnimate bower version: `bower install angular-animate#1.2.6 --save`

Comment: @Anchor's solution worked for me as well. Still doesn't explain why this an issue in the first place.

Comment: I have the same version in angular and in angular-animate (1.3.15), but it still complains, any clue?

Comment: Have you tried a different version of angular-animate or upgrading AngularJS? I currently have AngularJS 1.3.14 and Animate ~1.3.14 in my bower file and everything seems to be fine.

Comment: I tried the lastest stable version as well, I'm using npm and webpack

Comment: After modifying the top level bower.json, I had to: `rm -rf bower_components ; bower cache clean ; bower install` to pick up the changes.

Comment: As posted in my answer below - using same angular and angular-animate versions works best.

Comment: My conflict was between animate 1.3.20 and angular 1.3.17.  But thanks to @Anchor I was able to downlevel ngAnimate and it works.  THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 59):

The problem here is that the Angular version does not match to the angular-animate version. Try to keep them aligned, so if you use angular 1.2.6, also use angular-animate 1.2.6.

Also you have to clean you bower components (delete the bower folder) after you make changes in the bower.json, bower will not check if the version installed is the same as in the bower.json

Generally I would recommend using the highest available stable angular and ng-animate version if you can.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is probably due to compatibility issue. Though changing the angular version in bower.json would solve the problem, But the best way to solve this problem is to get the latest copy of angular and angular-animate i.e ~1.4.0

And the best part is asyncCallback is not being used in the latest version. So no such error would come. :p

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I used angular animate 1.3.4 with angular 1.4.8. After down grade the angular version to 1.3.4, error gone.

Answer (score 0):

In your **bower.json** file

find and change to `"angular": "1.5.8"`
and than type command `bower update`