# angularjs error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the following error with angularJS:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- $compile

I have rolled back my bit bucket code to an older version, and it is still persisting. Any idea how I can fix this and what is causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Which code should I provide - app.js?

Comment: Maybe a similar version issue as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661187/angular-animate-unknown-provider-asynccallbackprovider-asynccallback

Comment: @Mad-C is probably right. Check the link out.

Comment: fixed it, there was a problem with the animate package - used bower to update

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you need to ensure angular and angular-animate versions are aligned. For detail answer, please refer to [Angular-animate - Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- $compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661187/angular-animate-unknown-provider-asynccallbackprovider-asynccallback)

Hopefully this is helpful :)