# Angular-animate not working with Ui Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-animate

I'm using `"angular-animate": "^1.5.0"` with `"angular": "1.5.0"` and `"angular-bootstrap": "^1.2.4"`.

I've implemented my app.js as:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngAnimate',
    'facebook',
    'ngMap',
    'ngCookies',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'ui-notification',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'btford.socket-io',
    'templates'
]);
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$AnimateRunnerProvider <- $$AnimateRunner <- $animateCss <- $uibModalStack <- $animateCss
```

When I comment out `ngAnimate` from the dependencies, my `ui-bootstrap` carousel and related elements work but without the slide transitions but when I add the `ngAnimate` dependency, it breaks completely. How should I fix this?

Comment: Did you add the script on your html page ?

Comment: It could be linked to the angular version, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661187/angular-animate-unknown-provider-asynccallbackprovider-asynccallback

Comment: Try including different older versions of angular-animate.js

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue, 
in bower.json I have

```
"resolutions": {
   "angular": "^1.0.8"
}
```

and changed to

```
"resolutions": {
  "angular": ">=1.4.0"
}
```

I am using `"angular": "1.5.3" and "angular-bootstrap": "1.3.2"` and the resolution is too low to version 1.0.8, might be that caused the issue, and **AnimateRunner** is added from `"angular": "1.4.0`