# ngMaterial for date picker is not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, angular-material

I need a date picker in input box. Searched around and found ngMaterial provides features like that.

I did all required file inclusion but getting error.

> angular.js:68Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- $compile

In **index.html** I want to show date picker for date of birth field.

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                       <md-datepicker ng-model="answers.myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>                    
                </div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("autoQuote", ["ui.router", "ngResource","ngMaterial"]);
...
```

Please help me to find, what I am missing here?

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/aV65Nab9U9I6YlK2g4sY?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working Plunker**:  https://plnkr.co/edit/F0iWzJqWeidDDSpFY9zK?p=preview

**First Mistake**:
Use Same Version for All Angular Libraries:

Your are using **angular**: **v1.5.7** and **angular-animate**: **v1.3.15**
so first fix this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
```

**Second Mistake**:
Inject ngAnimate Dependency:

```
 var app = angular.module("autoQuote", ["ui.router", "ngResource","ngAnimate","ngMaterial"]);
```

Hope This Helps!

Comment: I don't want right arrow to open date picker calendar.  I wan calendar to be open when user focus in text box. but he should not be able to type in text box.

Comment: If you want to open calendar on focus set md-directive ==>> "md-open-on-focus" ||
or read documentation for more configurations.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker

Comment: can we use this directive as attribute? I need to fix many ui issue. like I want o show it left and as below input box.

Comment: Yes Angular Directive support 4 Types:
'A' - only matches attribute name,
'E' - only matches element name,
'C' - only matches class name,
'M' - only matches comment.

Read this for more information: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I am asking about ngAnimate directive.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your ng-animate does not match the angular.js version does it?
Same? problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23695753/732846)