# Is it possible changing angular 1.3.9 to angular 1.6.5(current version)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, version-control

I have replaced angular 1.3.9 to angular 1.6.5 and I got this console error.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- compile

I have changed nothing on my main angular code.
All services and controllers are same.
Any kind of hint will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Paul Weber on this [thread right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661187/angular-animate-unknown-provider-asynccallbackprovider-asynccallback), you need to check if the version of the angular-animate you are using matches the new version of AngularJS you just updated (1.6.5).

Comment: Great hint, I make it succes via your answer

Answer (score 0):

If services are injected into your controller, **all services should be in array**, check it for all.

May this help.

Comment: What does all services  should be in array mean? can you describe more detail?

Comment: angular.module('app').factory('CTRLname',
        ['common', 'entityManagerFactory', 'systemService', 'imageService', dataContext]);

    function dataContext(common, entityManagerFactory, systemService, imageService) {
});